# trying to output all odd numbers from a sentinel loop, almost got it but not quite and also want to know why I am doing what needs to be done

Tags: c++

Hi so I have to write this program, Write a sentinel controlled while loop.
Ask user to input integer numbers. Output all odd numbers. Program quits when the value:
-999 is entered.  I have most the program functioning correctly except inputting multiple numbers and outputting only odd numbers, I created the program below and it quits the program at -999 and asks for input and outputs odd numbers, but I have tried to get it to do what the program requires and have been having issues getting it to input multiple integers and outputting just the odd ones. My program is posted below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SENTINEL = -999;
    int num;

    cout << "Enter a number to stop enter -999  " << endl;
    cin >> num;

    while (num != SENTINEL)
    {
        if (num % 2 != SENTINEL)
            cout << "odd integer is: "  << num << endl;
        cout << " Enter a number " << endl;
        cin >> num;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this, and it never fails to work. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using short, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Consider what `if (num % 2 != SENTINEL)` does. Does anything in your instructions indicate that the sentinel value should be involved if determining a number is odd?

Answer (score 1):

to test if num is an odd, use:

`if (num % 2)` instead of `if (num % 2 != SENTINEL)`

because the remainder is calculated when divided by 2 using the % modulus operator, if it isn't zero this integer is odd, your test `!= SENTINEL` doesn't really make sense.